# WebStorm: how to add jsx file type to 'File > New' list

Tags: webstorm, reactjs

Does anybody know, if it's possible to modify this list? In particular, I'd like to add there jsx file type.

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Settings | Editor | File and Code Templates, press `+` (Insert) to create a new template, set `Extension` to `jsx`, specify a name that should appear in New menu - that's all. You can also add some code to get the file pre-populated with some contents on creation. See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.1/file-and-code-templates-2.html

Comment: Turned out to be so easy. Thanks!